# Have aggregate function group results in one row

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a table that has the following columns:

- debit
- credit
- payment_method
- class

Now I will perform this query:

```
 select sum(debit - credit), payment_method, class 
 from my_table 
 group by payment_method, class
```

And since I have various payment methods and various classes, I will have several rows of the result set.

Now I want to be able to aggregate this result and have the output grouped by class only, for example for a certain class `001` I want to have: 
`payment_method1, sumofpayment_method1, payment_method2, sumofpayment_method2, payment_method3, sumofpayment_method3` in one row.

Is it possible in Postgres 9.1?

Update:

The table definition is as follows:-

- debit numeric(10,2)
- credit numeric(10,2)
- payment_method varchar(20)
- class varchar(25)

Comment: Will you have exactly three pairs (payment method and sum) for every class?

Comment: You should provide a full table definition with column data types.

Comment: @dezso not really they could be more than three. I used three for illustration purposes only

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I have edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the `crosstab()` function provided by the additional [module tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html).

Then your function could look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
   'SELECT class, payment_method, sum(debit - credit) AS saldo
    FROM   tbl
    GROUP  BY 1,2
    ORDER  BY 1,2'

   ,$$VALUES 
        ('payment_method1'::text), ('sumofpayment_method1')
      , ('payment_method2'), ('sumofpayment_method2')
      , ('payment_method3'), ('sumofpayment_method3')$$
   )
AS ct (class text
     , payment_method1 numeric, sumofpayment_method1 numeric
     , payment_method2 numeric, sumofpayment_method2 numeric
     , payment_method3 numeric, sumofpayment_method3 numeric);
```

I am using all 6 "types" you mentioned. Well, I see that only half of them are actually intended as type. Either way, substitute your actual types.
[More details, links and explanations in this related answer on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Comment: u have an idea why I get this error:- `function crosstab(unknown, unknown) does not exist  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` I have install tablefunc module

Comment: @G.Ngotho: Did you install the additional module tablefunc as instructed in the linked answer? And do you have the schema (usually `public`) in your `search_path`? (`SHOW search_path;`)

Comment: Well I ran `CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc` and I got `error ERROR:  type "tablefunc_crosstab_2" already exists` And yes I have the schema public in my search path

Comment: @G.Ngotho: Do you have half an installation carried over from an older version of Postgres maybe? Then you'd have to sanitize your installation: Delete all existing tablefunc objects until you can run a complete new installation. Try [`DROP EXTENSION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-dropextension.html) first. You can also check the list of functions in your public schema to begin with.