# Schema for analytics table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, optimization, data-warehouse, star-schema

We use Postgres for analytics (star schema).
Every few seconds we get reports on ~500 metrics types.
The simplest schema would be:

```
timestamp      metric_type     value
78930890       FOO              80.9
78930890       ZOO              20
```

Our DBA has came up with a suggestion to flatten all reports of the same 5 seconds to:

```
timestamp   metric1     metric2     ...  metric500
78930890    90.9        20          ...
```

Some developers push back on this saying this adds a huge complexity on development (batching data so it is written in one shot) and to maintainability (just looking at the table or adding fields is more complex).

Is the DBA model the standard practice in such systems or only a last resort once the original model is clearly not scalable enough?

EDIT: the end goal is to draw a line chart for the users. So queries will mostly be selecting a few metrics, folding them by hours/minutes, and selecting min/max/avg per hour (or any other time period).

EDIT: The DBA main argument is that reducing the number of rows x500 times will allow more efficient indexes and memory (the table will contain hundreds of millions of rows before this optimization). Then when selecting multiple metrics the suggested schema will allow one pass over the data instead of separate index search for each metric.

EDIT: 500 metrics is an "upper bound" but in practice most of the time only ~40 metrics are reported per 5 seconds (not the same 40 though)

Comment: Well, in general I definitely wouldn't do the 500 columns.  In order to decide in your specific case, one should know how do you access this data - how the typical queries look like and so on.

Comment: thanks, please see edit with new information. What is the the problem you see with 500 columns - maintainability or performance?

Comment: Arguments from both sides are valid. The best result depends on the details. Exact data type? All 500 metrics are the same type? For your use cases: A "few metrics" from where exactly? What min/max/avg will be calculated *exactly*. For overall aggregates (taking all 500 metrics from a whole time range into account) the normalized schema (one value per row) would be considerably easier to use and faster. Storage size for the flattended schema would be drastically smaller, though. We are talking about an order of magnitude (decimal).

Comment: Storage is less important now for optimization, we are focusing on query times. The DBA believes that less rows are a key to improve here, especially with queries that will utilize a few metric from the same row. Data type is int or double for all 500 metrics. user will choose 1 to 5 metrics for a report and query their behavior over time (line chart). User will ask to fold results (e.g. get one value for each metric in an hour) based on an aggregation function (min, max, avg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, arguments from both sides are valid. Let's call them "star" (the flattened schema of your DBA) and "EAV" (entity-attribute-value). The latter can serve as a hint. Details in this related answer:
[Is there a name for this database structure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-there-a-name-for-this-database-structure)

Well, if your 500 metrics are of well known type and you don't invent new ones / drop old ones all the time, it's not the worst case EAV scenario, but similar.

There is **no "standard" way** to do it. The more flexible approach would be the "EAV" schema. Then you can easily add and delete metric-types: add a row to the referenced `metric_type` table, or delete one (cascading to metrics table). That would need a schema-change and be more expensive in the "star" model.

You can do quite a bit for either model with smart [covering / partial / multicolumn indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes.html).

#### Some decision guidance

Aggregates (min/max/avg/...) on a *single* metric-type? -> "star"
Aggregates considering *all or many* different metrics? -> "EAV"

Do these attributes describe a common entity? -> "star"
Or is it just a bunch of numbers that may be grouped / split up any other way? -> "EAV"

Your data is written once and then never changed? -> "star"
Or do you run UPDATES on selected metrics? -> "EAV"

Is your set of 500 metrics complete? The set hardly ever or never changes? -> "star"
New metrics are added, existing metrics are dropped all the time? -> "EAV"

#### Storage size

Concerning your comment:

> Storage is less important now for optimization, we are focusing on query times.

Storage size is a *major* factor for query times. The number of data pages that have to be read to satisfy a query is probably the most important single factor for performance.

Let's start with your casual remark: `Data type is int or double`.

[`int` occupies 4 bytes.

`double` occupies 8 bytes.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html)

Assuming all columns are `NOT NULL`, 500 integer columns, plus 1 timestamp plus row overhead (no padding) would occupy 2036 bytes in the "star" schema. No compression possible. Here is how you calculate that:
[Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

If you mix `int` with `double`, be sure not to waste space for padding. For instance, group integer and double metrics.

In the "EAV" model, you'd need at least 44 or 52 bytes per row. 22000 or 26000 bytes for one timestamp. 11 - 13 times as much. That matters. For one hour's worth of data, you need to fetch 2000 data pages or more (default page size 8k) vs. around 180 pages for the "star" schema.

Here are some tools to measure size:
[Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row/23933#23933)

I think storage size can be the key to performance here. If you are `focusing on query times`, and I had to make a wild guess, the **"star" schema is probably the better choice**.

But as I said, it depends on a lot of details.

---

Either way, you may be interested in cross tabulation ("pivot table"). The [`tablefunc` module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) provides the `crosstab()` function:
[Have aggregate function group results in one row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46837/have-aggregate-function-group-results-in-one-row/46842#46842)

Comment: Thanks! Would it matter if the number 500 is an "upper bound" but in practice most of the time only ~40 metrics are reported per 5 seconds (not the same 40 though)?

Comment: @user2976991: That would clearly weigh in favor of the "EAV" model. Be aware, though, that NULL storage in the "star" model is also very cheap: ~ 1 bit per column. [More about that](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52639/what-is-the-default-size-of-text-field-in-postgres/52659#52659)